# Python - Reoccurring Bug in my Rock, Paper, Scissors code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on developing a python program for school regarding a paper, scissors, rock game. I have written the program and can run it, but I am noticing that when playing different hands, I'm still getting Tie result on some.

The mentors have given me feedback regarding this:
"For your project to be complete, you still need to implement the "learn()" method in the ReflectPlayer and CyclePlayer classes.

Note: According to the specification, you must implement this method in the classes where it is necessary to remember the last move (my_move in CyclePlayer and their_move in ReflectPlayer).

Specification:

> Some computer players don't need to remember anything, so their remembering method should do nothing.
> In the Player class, you must leave only the method signature.

```
def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
pass
```

- I cant find out what I need to add as I think have the correct data added. Can someone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkB96.png)

```
import random
import colorama
from colorama import Fore 

colorama.init()
print(Fore.GREEN)

"""This program plays a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors between two Players,
and reports both Player's scores each round."""

moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

"""The Player class is the parent class for all of the Players
in this game"""

class Player:
    moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.score = 0
        self.name = name
        self.my_move = 'init'
        self.ai = random.choice(self.moves)
        self.human = self.moves

    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
        self.human = my_move
        self.ai = their_move

    def move(self):
        return 'rock' 

def beats(one, two):
    return ((one == 'rock' and two == 'scissors') or
            (one == 'scissors' and two == 'paper') or
            (one == 'paper' and two == 'rock'))

class HumanPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        valid_input = False
        while not valid_input:
            humanmove = input('Rock, Paper or Scissors? -- ')
            if humanmove.lower() not in moves:
                print(">>>Try again!<<<\n")
            else:
                return humanmove
        return valid_input

class RandomPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        return random.choice(moves)

class CyclePlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        if self.human == self.moves[0]:
            return self.moves[1]
        elif self.human == self.moves[1]:
            return self.moves[2]
        else:
            return self.moves[0]

class ReflectPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        return self.ai

class Game:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.winner = 'init'
    def play_round(self):
        self.p1.human = self.p1.move()
        self.p2.human = self.p2.move()
        print(f"Agent Smith: {self.p1.human} - Neo: {self.p2.human}")
        self.p1.learn(self.p1.human, self.p2.human)
        self.p2.learn(self.p2.human, self.p1.human)
        self.conclude_round_winner()

    def conclude_round_winner(self):
        if (beats(self.p1.human, self.p2.human)):
            self.p1.score += 1
            print(f'{self.p1.name} is the Winner!')
        elif (beats(self.p2.human, self.p1.human)):
            self.p2.score += 1
            print(f'{self.p2.name} is the Winner!')
        else:
            print("Tie!")
            
    def conclude_game_winner(self):
        if (self.p1.score > self.p2.score):
            self.winner = self.p1
        elif (self.p2.score > self.p1.score):
            self.winner = self.p2

    def play_game(self):
        print("Hello Neo... want to enter The Matrix? All you need to do is beat Agent Smith in Rock, Paper, Scissors...")
        for round in range(1, 5):
            print(f'Score: Neo: {self.p2.score} | Agent Smith: {self.p1.score} \nRound {round} Begin:')
            self.play_round()
        self.conclude_game_winner()
        if (self.winner != 'init'):
            win_text = f'The Simulation is Over, {self.winner.name} is your Winner!\n'
            print(win_text)
        else:
            win_text = 'Draw!'
            print('Draw!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game(CyclePlayer('Agent Smith'), HumanPlayer('Neo'))
    game.play_game()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkB96.png)

Comment: Your indentation looks odd, do you mean for your `Player` class to have every other class within it? The code as is does not work on VSCode as it says `Player is not defined`. Your `def beats:` is missing the argument `(self, ...)` too. I moved all of the classes outside of the `Player` class to test with it but could you confirm how your code is meant to look and be structured please

Comment: Hi James, 

Thanks for assisting.

I think the indentations were jumbled up as I was inserting it within the code area of the questions page. 

https://github.com/citiz3nfive/RPS.Matrix.git 

Here is the repository I uploaded it within. 

In VScode i am able to run it within the terminal which i will link a picture of below. 
Let me know if this makes it run better for you.

Comment: instead of link to GitHub  better put code again, select it, and use `Ctrl+K`

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: @furas thank you so much for that, this was my first quesiton on here so i wasnt sure how to go about it. 

I will mend that and put the code within here with the Ctrl+K function. 

Thanks mate

Comment: I have mended the code within the question. Thanks @furas

Comment: you display text `Tie` in `conclude_round_winner()` - so maybe first use `print()` to see what you get in `self.p1.human, self.p2.human`  when you run `beats()` in `conclude_round_winner()`

Comment: in `HumanPlayer.move` you `return humanmove` but you should `return humanmove.lower()`.OR you should run `humanmove = input(...).lower()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 1):

In `HumanPlayer.move()` you `return humanmove` but you should `return humanmove.lower()`.

OR you should run `humanmove = input(...).lower()`

Comment: Thank you Furas, i will try this and let you know.